# Android: Where is the correct place to make a http request in a List Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, listadapter

I have a List Adapter for a listview  in my one activity,

Now I want to populate this list view with data I obtain from a web service.  Where is the correct place to execute a async request to the server to obtain the json data to populate the adapter?

1: before I instantiate the adapter and passing it through as a constructor?
     But then I dont know how refreshing will work.

2: Some where in the adapter?

2.1: in the adapters constructor?

2.2 Some where in the get view?

Here is my adapter so far:

```
public class MyDevicesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private String TAG = "MyDevicesAdapter";

// Keep all Objects in array
private ArrayList<MyDevice> devices;

/**
 * Constructor for creating a my devices list adapter
 * 
 * @param context
 *            The context of the calling class
 */
public MyDevicesAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    devices = new ArrayList<MyDevice>();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return devices.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return devices.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Checks if the List is empty
 */
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return devices.isEmpty();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_device_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.my_device_item_ImageView);
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.my_device_item_textView_name);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Temp variable to store the current list item
    final MyDevice DeviceItem = (MyDevice) getItem(position);

    //Set Image

    //Set Name


    //on click listener for the view
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "Deleting order in position : " + position);
        //deleteOrder(orders.get(position), position, v);
        }
    });

    return null;
}

/**
 * Private View holder class Keeps a reference to the View for the certain
 * components. Is used to increase performance of the listView
 */
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtName;
}
}
```

Here is the Async Request that's going to fetch my data:

```
Network.login("mydevices",null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                byte[] responseBody) {          
        }   

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            // Response failed :(
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you talk in about ListView refreshing?

Comment: As per my opinion make Request into `Background` using `AsyncTask` and set your `Adapter` to `ListView` into `onPostExecute(.....)`

Comment: By the way the last line of your `getView()` seems to be wrong.

Comment: In **getView()** method replace this **return null;** to **return convertView;**

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere else ;)

Based on your app you can trigger the download from any position. But you should do the work in a seperat thread or by using an AsyncTask. So this will not block your UI. If the data are available just notify the listeners by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` and you are done. The UI will been reloaded automatically after that call.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the adapter and list and then call async task. 
In the post method you can call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() for the changes to list every time you update it.

Answer (score 0):

Get the data in your initialize progress.

Let your adapter know it by a CallBack(Adapter implements the callback interface and register it to the AsyncTask,when work is down,the AsyncTask do the callback).

Answer (score 0):

Create an ArrayList (or any form the way you want to pass your data) depending upon the type of data you have to pass to your adapter. In the onCreate pass that as a parameter to your adapter even if it is blank. You wont get any data at this point.

Then on a separate thread, lets say Asynctask get the data and add it to your ArrayList. Post this simply call

```
 adapter.setNotifyDataSetChanged();
```

This will automatically refresh your List and populate it with the latest values of your ArrayList. ListView's are designed in this manner, that every time a call is made to notifyDataSetChanged() it will refresh itself depending upon the data it was initialised with.

Comment: Oh ok I see. So I initialize and display an empty list. Then I can display a loading sign. I then execute my request to get data: once it has loaded the data. I can hide the loading sign, and then refresh the list?

Comment: Correct, awesome you got the point :) Just remember to make the request to your web service in a separate thread (Asynctask). It has a post execute method in which you can do the list refresh part. See this - http://www.developerfusion.com/article/145373/android-listviews-with-dynamic-data/    It only misses the progress part but thats a cakewalk. :)

Comment: Cakewalk? :-D Did you play too much Portal?

Comment: @rekire - Hehe nopes :). Zapnologica - let know if this works for you and you need help.